# Using OpenCSV library throws runtime exception ListValuedMap 'Class not found'

Tags: java, spring-boot, opencsv

I am using OpenCsv to parse a CSV file and running in Spring Boot. I get a runtime exception, 
`ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections4.ListValuedMap`

I have collections 4.4 in my build path in IntelliJ Community Edition.

```
 [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections4.ListValuedMap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
```

[image: screenshot showing apache collections 4.4 in maven]

**Update:** I did a clean and build on the project and then somehow it said 'updating snapshots' and then the error went away.